# Why is Protoc 3.0.0 breaking Make Install of Bitcoin source?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, bitcoin-qt-setup

I am trying to build bitcoin from source, and am running into some problems with `protoc`, when I run `sudo make install` on the source code I get a version error for protoc:

```
sudo make install
Making install in src
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/q/plusonecoin-master/src'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/q/plusonecoin-master/src'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/q/plusonecoin-master'
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/q/plusonecoin-master'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/q/plusonecoin-master/src/secp256k1'
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/q/plusonecoin-master/src/secp256k1'
  CXX      qt/qt_plusonecoin_qt-bitcoin.o
In file included from qt/paymentrequestplus.h:10:0,
                 from qt/paymentserver.h:35,
                 from qt/bitcoin.cpp:24:
qt/paymentrequest.pb.h:12:2: error: #error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is
 #error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is
  ^
qt/paymentrequest.pb.h:13:2: error: #error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers. Please update
 #error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers.  Please update
  ^
qt/paymentrequest.pb.h:14:2: error: #error your headers.
 #error your headers.
  ^
qt/paymentrequest.pb.h:22:35: fatal error: google/protobuf/arena.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:8410: recipe for target 'qt/qt_plusonecoin_qt-bitcoin.o' failed
make[2]: *** [qt/qt_plusonecoin_qt-bitcoin.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/q/plusonecoin-master/src'
Makefile:9487: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/q/plusonecoin-master/src'
Makefile:682: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

I have tried building it with Protoc 2.4.1, 2.6.1, 3.0.0 and 3.2.0 but they all throw the same error. What is causing this error and how do I resolve this version issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running `make clean`. This error throws when you installed a different protobuf version.